# Three.js rotating an object smoothly inside a function

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, rotation

I have built a Rubik's Cube using Three.js and its all working, but I would like to animate the turning of the cube. Right now, when I turn one side it just snaps into the new position. How can I let it turn slowly?

The code I use right now:

```
function turnOrangeSide(inverse) {
    let x = 0;
    let y = 1;
    let z = 1;
    orangeGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
    scene.add(orangeGroup);

    //This puts all the parts of the Cube that have to be turned in the group.
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y, z + 1));
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y, z - 1));
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y + 1, z));
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y - 1, z));
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y + 1, z + 1));
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y - 1, z + 1));
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y + 1, z - 1));
    orangeGroup.attach(getIntersecting(rotationPointO, x, y - 1, z - 1));

    let rotation = Math.PI / 2
    if (inverse) rotation = -Math.PI / 2
    orangeGroup.rotation.x += rotation;
}
```

Live example at https://rekhyt2901.github.io/AlexGames/RubiksCube/RubiksCube.html.

Answer (score 1):

What you could actually do is to use a parametric equation to rotate your cube progressively around an axe.
That would give something like :

```
let fps = 60;           // fps/seconds
let tau = 2;            // 2 seconds
const step = 1 / (tau * fps);  // step per frame
const finalAngle = Math.PI/2;
const angleStep = finalAngle * step;
let t = 0;

function animateGroup(t){
   if (t >= 1) return; // Motion ended
   t += step;  // Increment time
   orangeGroup.rotation.x += angleStep; // Increment rotation
   requestAnimationFrame(() => animateGroup(t));
}

animateGroup(t);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works really well. I had to adapt it a little but it works properly and actually made my code cleaner, thank you!